# How to open new selenium session for every login?

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a website using python and selenium. I have define function for login and open selenium browser.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def authentication():
    return jsonify(message=authenticate(username, password), success=1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument("start-maximized")
 options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
 options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
 options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
 options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
 options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
 options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
 options.add_argument('--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor')
 options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
 # options.add_argument("--headless")
 browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver')
 options.add_argument("--example-flag")
 wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)


 app.debug = True
 app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

when I run its opening a selenium browser and I get this

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

when i go to the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in the selenium browser process happens and I'm getting the correct result. But the problem is when open the above URL in another tab its not opening new selenium browser instead it is doing the process in already opened selenium browser how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create chrome profile for every new user and save it . if user is login for first time crate new chrome profile and if already login use previous profile .

Answer (score 0):

you must remove `--remote-debugging-port`  and don't use `user-data-dir` option.
Selenium always starts a new session when you don't use these options.

Comment: I want to start new session every time while keep others alive